# git svn clone error message (author name not defined and Index mismatch)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to convert a svn.dump file to a git repo and I get the following error message after it started the process and it stops at r1648 with the following error message.

Index mismatch: 050a0cc9f86e0ba2453d3baed3f069e1d1fe1477 != c321ff4e94b18147619ce9fbd0324ea0f4323d29 rereading 06ed9207b02ea9e7d8af270c71c6012311a275c9
D   sites/voices/css/ie-only.css W: -empty_dir: trunk/sites/voices/css/ie-only.css`
Author: Vish Chou  not defined in /Users/vc/Sites/voices/authors.txt file

Here are the contents of the author.txt file which I got after running the following command:

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors.txt
```

authors.txt content

Brian = Brian <Brian>

Jlanglo = Jangle <Jlanglo>

Vish Chouh = Vish Chou <Vish Chou> - **This user is causing the issue.**

admin = admin <admin>

chiudesign = chiudesign <chiudesign>

clarkk = clarks <clarkk>

When I run the following command:

```
svn log | sed -n '/Vish Chou/,/-----$/ p'
```

to see the log submitted by this specific author I get the following message

> r1648 | Vish Chou  | 2013-12-02 14:27:43 -0500 (Mon, 02 Dec 2013) | 1
>   line

Comment: Put double quotes around the name.

Comment: "Vish Chou" - this name already exists in the authors.txt but I still get the error. I am not sure if its the space in between or I have to format the authors.txt file to get this to work. I am following the instructions from this site [link] (http://sebastian.formzoo.com/2010/11/04/3-steps-convert-svn-dump-to-git/)

Comment: @bahrep, did you get a chance to look at the error again?

Comment: put double quotes " " around the username in authors.txt file. `"Vish Chou"`.

Comment: @bahrep, tried but I still get the same error message. "Author: Vish Chou  not defined in /Users/vc/Sites/voices/authors.txt file"

Answer (score 0):

> "Vish Chou" - this name already exists in the `authors.txt` but I still get the error.

Does it exist, though?

Because you mention:

```
Vish Chouh = Vish Chou <Vish Chou> 
     ^^^^^        ^^^^
```

For testing, I would repeat the process with:

```
Vish Chou = Vish Chou <Vish Chou> 
       ^^^
```

Meaning, with an *identical* name  on both side of the '`=`'